# How to specify optional argument for a command operator invokation?

Tags: powershell

I have the following command call

```
& ".\script1.ps1" -switch1 "$DBN" "$($Server[-1])" "$Creds" "$ConnectionID" "$ConnectionDataSource"
```

I want to make ConnectionID and Connection DataSource optional

How can I do that?

This command is only working if I input something for ConnectionID and Connection Data Source. otherwise, they won't work if I don't input anything for these two params!

here are the params in this script1.ps1 (which I am calling IN script2.ps1):

```
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$DBN,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Server,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
[ValidateScript({![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Trim())})]
    [string]$Creds,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$false, HelpMessage="Enter a UserID for the connection")]
[ValidateScript({![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Trim())})]
[string]$ConnectionID, 

[Parameter(Mandatory=$false, HelpMessage="Enter a Data Source for the connection. Must enter the ConnectionID first")]
[ValidateScript({![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Trim())})]
[string]$ConnectionDataSource
)
```

here are the params in this script2.ps1 (which I am calling script1.ps1 from):

```
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$DBN,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$false, HelpMessage="Enter a UserID for the connection")]
[string]$ConnectionID, 

[Parameter(Mandatory=$false, HelpMessage="Enter a Data Source for the connection. Must enter the ConnectionID first")]
[string]$ConnectionDataSource
)
```

running script1.ps1 without these 2 inputs works just fine.

i run it like this:

```
PS> script1.ps1 DB1 Server1
```

so I know I have to do something here in the call operator of this second script I'm calling script1 from

I'm looking for something like this:

```
& ".\script1.ps1" -switch1 "$DBN" "$($Server[-1])" "$Creds" [optional]"$ConnectionID" [optional]"$ConnectionDataSource"
```

Comment: Possible throw in an `If` statement. `if(-not $ConnectionID) { $ConnectionID = "Default Value"}` This will allow you to either supply a connection ID or not. If no connection ID, then it will default to something.

Comment: @Drew unfortunately, the parameter has to be dynamic. its either what the user inputs, or what the default will be from HashVault :/

Comment: Can you write other parameters without omission? I think you can probably solve it using `ValueFromRemainingArguments`.

Comment: @rokumaru interesting,  can.you elaborate what you mean by without ommission

Comment: you said "This command is only working if I input something for ConnectionID and Connection Data Source" then you said "running script1.ps1 without these 2 inputs works just fine", can you please clarify you question more

Comment: @Cataster as stated by Shadowfax post the COMPLETE PARAM block in your question!

Comment: @Moerwald i updated my post, included params for script1

Comment: @Shadowfax i updated my post with complete params

Comment: @Shadowfax figured it out :) check my answer

Comment: @Moerwald figured it out :) check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! its because i have this in the script1.ps1 params

```
[ValidateScript({![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Trim())})]
```

by commenting out, or even replacing it with `[AllowNull]` attribute, it works!